# Basic Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to get a basic program going with the windows API (WinMain and WndProc) and have completed 4 tutorials now, all of which say the same thing.  I create the two vital functions previously mentioned but when I compile and run no window is shown.

I get no errors or crashes, the program runs fine it's just the window that should but doesn't appear.

Any help would be great, I've tried using a Win32 Console project setup, a Win32 project setup and an Empty Project setup in VS2010.

Thanks.

EDIT: Apologies, here is the code I am using to set up and show the window:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASS));

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASS);
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon = 0;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName = 0;
wcex.lpszClassName = "MyWindowClass";
wcex.hIconSm = 0;

RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "MyWindowClass",       // Name of window class
                         "Window Name",         // Title of window
                         WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,   // Window style
                         300, 500,              // x,y position of window
                         800, 600,              // w,h of window
                         NULL,                  // Parent window
                         NULL,                  // Menus
                         hInstance,             // Application handle
                         NULL);                 // Multiple windows

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
```

Comment: You need to provide some code in order to get help in your specific problem. It's impossible to help with the information you are providing.

Comment: Can you post the code that shows where you create the window? in my experience one of the parameters you pass in to CreateWindow is probably invalid

Comment: Apologies. Window set up code added. [Note: Have tried both CreateWindow and CreateWindowEx functions.]

Comment: Where's the message loop? And what about some error checking? RegisterClassEx or CreateWindowEx could easily fail.

Comment: David is right. You're missing the message loop. Easiest thing to do to get going in a hurry is creating a new Win32 project in Visual Studio. All the boilerplate code is automatically inserted, just build and run. You'll never get this to work with a console application.

Comment: @David, @Cody: Pretty sure he's only showing a small part of the file.

Comment: Ben's right, I have all the other code, only posted the window set up code.  I found what was wrong though, thanks for all your replies =)

Comment: Do not cast your window proc! Remove `(WNDPROC)`. And show your message loop and window proc function; they are equally important in solving this.

Comment: @Simon: Please remember that this isn't a site dedicated to helping you.  We're trying to build a humongous searchable database of common questions and solutions.  So please leave an answer saying what was wrong (and maybe the troubleshooting steps you used to find it) and then accept your answer.  Or accept whichever of our answers was most helpful.

Comment: @Ben: Yes I understand, the answer I posted myself solves the specific question I asked earlier, however I can't set that as the answer for 2 days (new member rule?).  I also can't vote up any other helpful answers til I have 15 reputation.  Don't want to seem ignorant, so those are the reasons.

Comment: I've just given your Q an up-vote which gives you +5 rep and so you are on your way to being able to up-vote!!

Comment: @Simon and one for your answer takes you over the magic 15 rep barrier!

Comment: @Simon: Consider checking that the return value of CreateWindowEx (hWnd) isn't NULL and displaying a MessageBox error message if it is. That way you'll know more about where the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASS));

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASS)
```

The above parameters should have been WNDCLASSEX to match the WNDCLASSEX structure defined just above them.

Comment: Actually, the best practice is probably to specify the name of the *variable itself*, rather than the structure. That way, whenever you change the variable's type, you don't have to hunt around looking for all the places you might have written code like this. Change that to: `ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(wcex));`

Comment: equivalent and even easier: `WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof wcex };

Answer (score 5):

```
 wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
```

That's a very fishy cast, it should *never* be necessary.  This problem is otherwise explained by a borked window procedure.  You didn't post it.  Start by deleting the cast and solve any compile error you get.  Make sure that it always calls DefWindowProc() for messages you don't process yourself.

Consider using the boilerplate code you get from selecting the Win32 Project project template to get these details right.

Answer (score 2):

There's a really great introduction to building your first Win32 application [available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx).

You won't get very far after that (the "next" link in the series starts teaching you about Windows Forms, which is humorous but irrelevant to your goal). But if your goal is just to learn what the boilerplate is, this is a great place to look.

Alternatively, as I mentioned in a comment, you should be able to create a new Win32 project in Visual Studio and get all that basic stuff inserted for you automatically. Of course, then you'll have the battle of *understanding* it all, but that's not what you're asking here. :-)

Here's the basic skeleton from that tutorial:

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application dows not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);    // send the window a WM_PAINT message

    // Main message loop:
    BOOL bRet;
    MSG msg;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,
                _T("Error encountered in message loop!"),
                _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
                NULL);

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get errors because you've not called `::GetLastError()`.  Print out the value returned by `GetLastError` after each API call.

Comment: -1:  Wrong answer.  He doesn't see a window because it is closed immediately with no message loop.

Comment: @Zac: Have you not read ANY of the comments?  The window wasn't created because the window class didn't exist.  The window class wasn't registered because the `cbSize` member had the wrong value.  Both of these errors caused the thread error code to be set, but Simon said he "got no errors" in the question.  He's literally correct, he didn't "get" errors with `GetLastError()`.

Comment: And even if he called `GetLastError` it wouldn't have mattered because the window would have still closed immediately.  And the `cbSize` parameter had the correct value size in the code he had posted when I created my post.  So either he fixed that prior, or it was a typo.

Comment: @Zac: Read the comments.  Simon had a message loop (not shown) which worked correctly.  Calling `GetLastError()` would most definitely have solved the problem because he would have immediately discovered that `RegisterClassEx` failed due to an invalid parameter.  The code in the question hasn't changed, `cbSize` doesn't have the correct value even now.  I'm not making up problems, [Simon told us what was wrong after he found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924305/basic-windows-api/4924535#4924535).

Comment: My apologies ... rough morning and I was taking it out on you.

Answer (score -1):

You have no message pump, so the window is being created and closed immediately.  Add the following to below your `ShowWindow` call:

```
    int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {0}; 
    wcx.cbSize          = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.style           = 0; 
    wcx.lpfnWndProc     = (WNDPROC)::DefWindowProc; 
    wcx.cbClsExtra      = 0; 
    wcx.cbWndExtra      = 0; 
    wcx.hInstance       = hInstance; 
    wcx.hIcon           = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
    wcx.hCursor         = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wcx.hbrBackground   = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH); 
    wcx.lpszMenuName    = NULL; 
    wcx.lpszClassName   = "DemoWindow"; 

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx( 0,                      // extended style
                                "DemoWindow",           // Window Class Name
                                "DemoWindow",           // Window Name
                                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // style
                                0,                      // x-position
                                0,                      // y-position
                                800,                    // width
                                600,                    // height
                                NULL,                   // parent HWND
                                NULL,                   // menu HANDLE
                                hInstance,              // instance HANDLE
                                NULL);                  // extra data

    if (NULL == hWnd)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); 
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg = {0};
    while(WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    { 
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
        else
        {
            // do something useful
        }
    } 

    UnregisterClass("DemoWindow", hInstance);
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: -1 This is **wrong, wrong, wrong**. `GetMessage` does *not* return `WM_QUIT`, and that's not how you write the message loop. Read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936.aspx) particularly the "Return Value" section.

Comment: Oops.  You are correct.  Its been so long since I wrote the loop by hand.  Fixed.

Comment: Error checking was left out since he had no other error checking in his original code.  The point was that he wasn't seeing a window because he had no message loop.  If you really want to be picky about it, I'll provide a very thorough implementation.

Comment: "he had no message loop"  Wrong.  Read the comments.  "he had no error checking in his original code"  True, and that's why he couldn't find the problem.